# How to find all the rows that match a list of combinations in Linq/SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Example object

```
public class Car
{
     public int Doors { get; set; }
     public int Wheels { get; set; }
}
```

To find all cars that match a list:

```
var list = new[] { 3, 4 };
var result = Db.Cars.Where( c => list.Contains(c.Doors) );
```

How to find all the cars that match one of the **combinations** of doors and wheels? I've tried:

```
var combinations = new[] { new Comb { Doors = 1, Wheels = 2 }, new Comb { doors = 5, wheels = 4 } };
var result = Db.Cars.Where( c => combinations.Contains(new Comb { Doors = c.Doors, Wheels = c.Wheels }) ) );
```

But of course this doesn't work,  giving the following error:

*Unable to create a constant value of type 'Example.Comb'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.*

Is there another way to do this?

Important part is that the amount of combinations is unknown.

Comment: Your `Comb` object looks just like a `Car` object.  What if you create a list of `Car` objects instead?

Comment: Hi Juharr, great tip and I tried it out. I'm affraid it gives me the same error for LinqToSql: *Unable to create a constant value of type 'Example.Car'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.*

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Db.Cars.Where(c=>combinations.Any(comb=>comb.Doors==c.Doors && comb.Wheels==c.Wheels));
```

Comment: This would throw the same exception.